# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.4' with Docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I'm currently learning to use Docker on Windows, and I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcZEbwxdg4Q). For Docker setup, I'm using Laradock. I'm trying to run *mysql apache2 rabbitmq and phpmyadmin* containers I did everything the same as in video, but when I try to migrate my tables I get following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.4' (using password: YES)

I created empty database in phpmyadmin.

Everything is configured in my projects .env and laradock/.env

My projects env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=*********
```

I double checked my password, and it's correct.

My laradock/.env configuration:

```
MYSQL_VERSION=latest
MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database_name
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=******
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
```

Docker-compose.yml configuration:

```
mysql:
  build:
    context: ./mysql
    args:
      - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
  volumes:
    - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
  networks:
    - backend
```

To ensure all of my containers are working, I enter this command and I get following response:

```
docker-compose ps
```

[Response from previous command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57vwj.png)

Root user in my phpmyadmin:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5opQ.png)

Comment: Did you check permissions for your user?

Comment: this user has all permissions, because it's my main user. I had no trouble connecting and running migrations while I was using XAMPP/phpmyadmin, but when I use docker, this happens

Comment: Could it be that docker can't connect to your XAMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue by changing my .env mysql username and password configuration to:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

And changing my mysql version in laradock/.env configuration to:

```
MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database_name
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

After that, I stopped all containers:

```
docker-compose down
```

Next step was to build mysql container with new configuration:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache mysql
```

Afther that, I run all of my containers again

```
docker-compose up -d mysql apache2 rabbitmq phpmyadmin
```

Navigated to workspace working direcory and migrated my tables:

```
php artisan migrate
```

And everything worked as intended:

> Migration table created successfully.
>
> Migrating: 2018_11_28_114446_create_accounts_table
>
> Migrated:  2018_11_28_114446_create_accounts_table

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can not create `root` user in docker's `.env` file. Root user is created by default and if you want to use it, just set a password for it: `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` in laradock. Then if you want to create **another** user, set `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`

So in laradock/.env file:

```
MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database_name
MYSQL_USER=myusername // any name other than root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootPassword // password to root user
MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Now you can use `root` user or `myusername` user in your laravel project:

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=rootPassword 

OR 

MYSQL_USER=myusername 
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Remember, for connecting to the correct database host in laradock, you should use `mysql` instead of `localhost or 127.0.0.1` in laravel:

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to `bind-address` accepting only localhost connections. Check out this example of how to use [custom mysqld.conf](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/275#issuecomment-307782167) in your mysql container

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I managed to setup everything on the other project last night,  and everything worked just fine. Had some similar errors, but managed to overcome them. But today, I can't do anything about this error.

Comment: That would produce a "connection refused" error, not a "permission denied" error.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Laradock, then everything is explained in *laradock/mariadb/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/createdb.sql.example*

you have to delete the folder $DATA_PATH_HOST/mariadb, and create your new user in */docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/myScript.sql*

Example:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'user'@'%' ;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

CREATE USER 'user' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL privileges ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `symfonydb1` COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who may encounter this problem, It has a very simple solution.

Just put your passwords in double quotations. Either in .env or docker-compose.yml

Comment: This was the answer for me. My password contained a `#`, which was somehow omitted without quotations. Both single and double quotations did the job for me.

Answer (score -1):

it was good for me:

```
rm -rf /root/.laradock
```